# How to Deploy Vite React Project on NameCheap cPanel?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, vite, cpanel, namecheap

I am trying to deploy my Vite react app on NameCheap cPanel but, I am unable to deploy my react app.

I run this command `npx vite build` to create a build of my react app. I got the **dist** folder in which **index.html** and **assets** folders are available. I simply go to cPanel select Node.js and create a node app. In the file manager, I upload the dist folder and zip in the exact folder that I created during the Node.js setup. I unzip the dist file and run the Node.js server. But I got a 503 error. I also tried to create a server.js file and in this file, I used express.js to call the dist and public folder, and then I uploaded server.js, package.json, and dist/public.zip files in cPanel. I also run the **Run NPM Install** to install all the dependencies but none of the methods works. Below is the image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAwt9.png)

If anyone knows how to deploy the Vite React project on NameCheap cPanel then please answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add .htaccess inside your public_html folder, like below

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Options +Indexes
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist/
 RewriteRule (.*) /dist/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```